# Netsuite calling REST API hosted outside

Tags: javascript, netsuite, restlet, suitescript

I am a newbie to Netsuite.

I have an app hosted outside say on AWS. This app has a REST API interface.
I would like to call my app/REST API *from* Netsuite. All the documentation I have seen so far,  point the other way i.e. calling REST API *hosted on* Netsuite.

I would appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction i.e. call a web service endpoint hosted outside of Netsuite from Netsuite scripts,  with a possible example.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `N/https` SuiteScript module.

```
var response = https.get({
  url: 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2021-04-01&endtime=2021-04-30'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Let me check it out.